# Forecast with regression model with scenarios

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, predict

I am running AR on this data.

```
   Date        Price     YOY    Quarter
   2000-01-15  2.385368 -312362      Q1
   2000-02-15  2.614250 -442117      Q1
   2000-03-15  2.828261 -252596      Q1
   2000-04-15  3.028842 -292756      Q2
   2000-05-15  3.596409 -401578      Q2
   ......
```

The model is

```
price.fit<-lm(log(Price)~+(YOY)+log(lag(Price))+relevel(Quarter,ref="Q4"),subset(Data,Year>=2000))
```

Now I need to forecast for the next 12 periods. A made-up data frame "newdata" includes estimate(a range) for the variable YOY.

```
newdata
high mean low
.....
```

How to use predict function or other method to forecast the price range(high, mean, low)for the next 12 months? Or maybe using loops?

Answer (score 1):

There is a generic function `predict()` and it can be used for prediction. Although `predict.lm()` is used below for clarification, `predict()` should work. Given a lm object and new data, it returns forecasted values.

As regression returns numeric values, converting into a factor (high, medium, low) has to be mapped manually and `sapply()` is used for that.

```
library(lubridate)
dates <- ymd(19990115) + months(0:71)
df <- data.frame(date = dates,
                 price = sample(100:150, 72, replace = T),
                 YOY = sample(-40000:-20000, 72, replace = T),
                 Qtr = as.factor(quarter(dates)))

price.fit <- lm(log(price) ~ +(YOY) + log(lag(price)) + relevel(Qtr, ref = "4"),
                data = df[year(df$date) >= 2000,])


pred <- predict.lm(price.fit, newdata = df[year(df$date) < 2000,])
pred
#1        2        3        4        5        6 
#4.976734 4.653960 4.605170 4.691348 4.663439 4.969813 
#7        8        9       10       11       12 
#4.927254 4.727388 4.634729 4.875197 4.700480 4.700480 

sapply(pred, function(x) {
  if(x < 4.56) "low"
  else if(x < 4.75) "medium"
  else "high"
})
#1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8 
#"high" "medium" "medium" "medium" "medium"   "high"   "high" "medium" 
#9       10       11       12 
#"medium"   "high" "medium" "medium"
```